# Confirmation of lease agreement

Tags: lease

In a digital lease is the lease valid if i do not send a signed copy of the lease they sent me? I do not intend on staying at the place.

Comment: Did you sign it or agree to it digitally? Did you actually stay at the place? Is this a residential lease? What jurisdiction are you (and the lessor) in?

Comment: yes this is a residential lease. i was planning to stay there and so pressed the sign digitally option upon which i received the lease in my inbox. There is a place for my signature and the site manger's signature both of which are blank. I am in India while the lesser is in Arlington, Texas.

Answer (score 1):

### Digital contracts are as valid as any other written contract

Assuming that you accepted the digital lease, you would be bound by it.

Comment: I never accepted it just chose to sign it digitally so that i could receive a copy of the lease in my inbox. The lease received has a place for signatures for both me and the lessor which is blank.

Comment: You signed it = you accepted it

Comment: Is there an option to terminate it before it takes effect? The lease is effective from 16th August.

Comment: I don’t know, you have the contract, I don’t. Is there?